# htaccess rewrite to use variable with slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have the index file where I include specific php files according to the p value.
It's working perfectly, but I want to add to new things.

1. The code should work the same with 
   http://mypage.com/contact
   and 
   http://mypage.com/contact/ (trailing slash)
2. I want to be able to use deeper URLs, but send them together to php
   http://mypage.com/contact/me
   I would like index.php, in this case, receive this variable "contact/me", which later I would separate to an array and work with it like that.

Also my little problem is, if I do this sub-URLs (with the lack of a better word), my CSS paths are messed up as the page thinks it is in the contact folder. Is it repairable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, your trailing slash is being gobbled up by the `[^.]+` expression, so you need to make that non-greedy by adding a `?` after the `+`. Otherwise, having multiple slashes in the URI should work with these rules. So this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

Needs to be this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

As far as the css goes, you either need to change the css links so that they're absolute URL paths (they start with a `/` and starts from the document root, e.g. `/css/my.css`) or you can try adding a relative URL base in the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/">
```

(or whatever the URL base should be).